# List of objects function not working

Tags: python, function

Sorry for the title, I hope it reflects correctly my problem :

In the following code, I was expecting the result to be result 0 1 2 but instead I have 2 2 2. The code inside *my_function* seems to be interpreted with the last instance of *obj*. What is wrong ?

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def get(self):
        return self.x

a_list = []
for index in range(3):
    obj = Example(index)

    def my_function(x):
        #some stuff with x like obj.another_function(x)
        return obj.get()

    a_list.append(my_function)

for c in a_list:
    print(c())
```

Comment: Is the code you posted here correctly indented?

Comment: There are a lot of problems in this code. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: no i correct it. Sorry

Comment: You're obviously redefining `my_function` at every iteration, so the last one overrides all the previous.

Comment: @barakmanos You're obviously wrong.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I admit that it's more of my personal interpretation, as I've never seen a function definition within a `for` loop (not quite used to that, though, I suppose that it might be a useful tool in non-typed languages in some way).

Comment: @barakmanos The functions are stored in `a_list`, where they're **not** overwritten. (And `a_list` is what's used at the end, so that's what matters.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understanding a few things about how python works will help you understand what's happening here. Here `obj` is a closure, closures are evaluated at call time, not when the function is defined so if I do this:

```
x = "hello"
def printX():
    print x
x = "goodbye"
printX() # goodbye
```

I get "goodbye" because `printX` is referencing a global variable in my module, which changes after I create `printX`.

What you want to do is create a function with a closure that references a specific object. The functional way to do this is to create a function that returns another function:

```
x = "hello"
def makePrintX(a):
    def printX():
        # We print a, the object passed to `makePrintX`
        print a
    return printX

# x is evaluated here when it is still "hello"
myPrintX = makePrintX(x) 

x = "goodbye"
myPrintX() # "hello"
```

If you're having trouble understanding the above example I would recommend reading up on python's scoping rules. For your example, you could do something like this:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def get(self):
        return self.x

def makeObjFunction(obj):
    def objFunction(x):
        return obj.get()
    return objFunction

a_list = []
for index in range(3):
    obj = Example(index)
    my_function = makeObjFunction(obj)

    a_list.append(my_function)

for c in a_list:
    print(c("some value"))
```

Answer (score 4):

When you define this

```
def my_function():
    return obj.get()
```

Python will understand that `my_function` should run the `get()` method of an object called `obj` and return the value. It won't know the value of `obj` and what the `get()` method does until you attempt to call it.

So, you are actually defining three different functions that will eventually do the **same** thing. And, in the end, running the **same** code thrice.

*But why is the return 2 2 2?*

Because after the last iteration, the value of `obj` is `Example(2)`* because you redefine its value at every iteration, and the last one remains.

*
*because of this line `obj = Example(index)`*

Comment: I find "same function" misleading, as they are three different function objects.

Comment: Beat me to it! Solution: `for i in range(3): a_list.append(Example(i).get());`

Answer (score 2):

You are appending three my_functions to the a_list which are all closures over the same Example object. Try:

```
def my_function():
    return obj

<__main__.Example object at 0x0054EDF0>
<__main__.Example object at 0x0054EDF0>
<__main__.Example object at 0x0054EDF0>
```

You can see they have the same id so calling get() on each should give the same answer.

If you just append the obj.get function (and drop the my_function) it'll work fine.

```
a_list.append(obj.get)
....
0
1
2
```

Edit: You've updated your question so to let you do more stuff in my_function(). It's still basically a scoping problem.

```
def my_func_factory(p_obj):
  def my_function(x):
    #some stuff with x like obj.another_function(x)
    return p_obj.get()
  return my_function

for index in range(3):
    obj = Example(index)
    a_list.append(my_func_factory(obj))
```

Since my_function can't see obj being reassigned, each instance doesn't pick up the change.

Comment: You are wrong. The 3 *`my_functions`* do **not** have the same address in memory

Comment: My code was simplified. In my_function I am doing some work like a set on the obj

Comment: @RafaelCardoso. I didn't say the three my functions had the same address. I said they all refer to the same Example object.

Comment: @benjamin. I've added a bit to my answer so you can use your custom function.

Answer (score 0):

I think `append()` during the `for` just append the function address in `a_list[]`. After `for` iteration, the `a_list` is really given the number. Then it discovers the address of `my_function`, and they get the number in `my_function`, this is, 2. That's why you get [2,2,2].

Or maybe, in `my_function`, function give the method of "obj". But `for` iteration change the "obj" memory address each time, so the symbol "obj" always aim to the newest object `Example`. Due to `my_function` always get "obj", you get the same number from the last object.